# Können vs Kenntnisse

Tags: word-usage

I looked up the German translation of 'proficiency' tonight and while I found 'Können' for 'proficiency' as a standalone word, 'proficiency in English' produced 'Kenntnisse in Englisch'. Can anyone explain the difference between the two words and how they might each be used?

Comment: It would be helpful to know how _proficiency_ is used in English. The best translation comes from knowing the context; and I lack business contacts that are native English speakers; i.e. I don´t have any experience with that word,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Profiency* should be translated with **Kenntnisse** only.

**»Das Können«** is the verb *können* (to be able to) made into a noun. It's closer to **ability** than *profiency*, though *ability* is often translated with *Fähigkeit*.

Usually, *»das Können«* describes a shirtsleeved form of ability.

> Du bist aber schnell fertig mit deiner Arbeit! — Tja, das ist halt Können.

*Well, you have your work done very quickly! — Gee, that's called a-b-i-l-i-t-y.*

Someone who *just can* do something is also described as a **Könner**.

Answer (score 1):

*Kenntnis* = *knowledge*

*Können* = *skill*

easy as that.

---

Looking at the [definition in the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proficiency), I´d say proficiency is **Können**.

[Merriam-Webster´s](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proficient) simple definition ("good at doing something") takes the same direction, while the full definition ("well advanced in an art, occupation, or branch of knowledge") allows both *Kenntnis* and *Können* imo. The [learner´s definition](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/proficient) ("good at doing something : skillful"), points at *Können* again.

---

This came just to my mind: *proficiency* sounds related to *profession*; and my stomach tells me that the closest translation is probably *Fertigkeit* or *Fähigkeit* ... in English: *skill* (again) afaik.

Answer (score 0):

*Können* refers to ability, while *kennen* does to knowledge and familiarity.

Generally, **proficiency** would thus be translated to *Können*.

In a language, however, *knowing* and *command* is more or less the same - Thus German has decided to translate **proficiency** with *Kenntnisse*. We don't normally refer to a language with *können* other than in colloquial German.

> Ich kann kein Englisch

Is a colloquial variant of

> Ich beherrsche die englische Sprache nicht

Which is a pretty literal translation of *I have no command of the English language*